# Specifications of Prusa Mini X-Axis Belt

Tags: replacement-parts, part-identification, belt, prusa-mini

My Prusa Mini arrived with a defective X axis belt. I can order a replacement and it is covered by warranty. But I would also like to know its specifications. [This information](https://shop.prusa3d.com/en/mini/1093-belt-x-axis.html) is available on the store page for the MK3 but not the Mini.

Comment: You might just ask them... They are pretty responsive to email or questions on their web site.

Answer (score 1):

To be sure you could measure the width and the tooth spacing (pitch). The most probable and used belt in 3D printers is the GT2 6 mm belt. The teeth are spaced 2 mm and the width is 6 mm.

[image]

[image]